# Computer Is Slow on First Loading, Even CPU and PF Usage is Minimum

Tags: windows-xp

I found that my computer is slow during bootup time and when I first open any application, even though the CPU and PF usage is minimum all the time. I have AVG free edition, and VM Workstation installed.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

Probably some application is initializing itself from the Internet, for example the antivirus downloading new virus definitions.

The antivirus may also be doing a small scan in order to start the day correctly.

Windows is always slow on startup, since there may be quite a few software products that need to initialize as well as access the Internet, and they do get in each other's way. If the desktop is displayed, this doesn't mean that you can already freely use the computer : you still need to wait 1-2 minutes for all the post-boot activity to quite down.

Comment: "Windows is always slow on startup." Did you learn that from some Apple commercial?

Comment: @hayoo: Life is the great teacher.

Answer (score 1):

> the CPU and PF usage is minimum

In TaskManager, View menu, select "Show Kernel Times" .

It will show am extra red line and I think your CPU is far from idle at startup.

Answer (score 0):

use **[BootVis](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/BootVis.shtml)** to track down the culprit(s). it's a performance trace visualization utility which will monitor the boot process and show in graphs the time it takes to load each driver and program.

then use [**Autouns**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) (Systinternals' startup manager) to disable unwanted/unnecessary programs.

**[Startup Delayer](http://www.r2.com.au/software.php?page=2&show=startdelay)** is another option to tweak the boot process even further (for those who do need a lot of programs to start with the system):

> If each program tries to do this at
>   the same time, you soon notice the
>   slow down that occurs, due to your CPU
>   trying to help all the programs to
>   load, and your hard disk accessing
>   multiple files.
>
> Startup Delayer allows you to setup
>   how many seconds after Windows has
>   started, to load each program.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Windows+R
2. Type "msconfig"
3. Go to the services tab
4. Click on "Hide all Microsoft services"
5. Click on "Disable All"
6. Go to Startup Tab
7. Click on Disable All.
8. Click OK.
9. Restart Your Machine.
   10.Enjoy the faster boot!

Comment: Very funny . . .

Comment: ????................????